# SQL query wordpress - how do I search for posts via regex (title) if they are also in a certain category - then add them to another category?

Tags: sql, regex, wordpress, categories, taxonomy

SQL Wordpress: want to search all posts with regex on the title that are also in a category - then add them to another category.

Want to do it in SQL not with wordpress. The category is called "under 100"

```sql
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title REGEXP '^(\$|£|€).. |^..(\$|£|€) ' AND
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id=wp_posts.ID
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id=wp_term_taxonomy.term_id 
WHERE name = 'under 100'
UPDATE wp_term_relationships SET term_taxonomy_id = 263
```

ahhh chaos not working